# @SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC) for web methods returning ArrayList

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

This was my web service code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)
public class ProductCatalog {

    public ArrayList<String> getProductCategories()
    {
        ArrayList<String> categories=new ArrayList<String>();
        categories.add("books");
        categories.add("movies");
        categories.add("music");

        return categories;

    }

}


      I have given `@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)` annotation, but this is not showing any effect in generated wsdl..
```

the generated wsdl is including a schema from external location only

```
 <types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://symp.com/" schemaLocation="http://rajasekhar_pc:9090/NewTestMart/ProductCatalogService?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
```

but when i change the web method return type to String then its working fine like

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)
public class ProductCatalog {

    public String getProductCategories()
    {


        return "Hello World";

    }

}
```

and the wsdl changes and its not refering to any external document

```
<types/>
<message name="getProductCategories"/>
<message name="getProductCategoriesResponse">
<part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
```

is there any way to get rpc style for return types array list... and even document stlyle soap inded wsdl is returning ArrayList object... i want the data

/////////// updated code///////////

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)

public class PatientsList {

@WebMethod
    public BeanList getpatientList()
    {
    BeanList bean=new BeanList();

        ArrayList<String> patientList=new ArrayList<String>();
        patientList.add("ajay");
        patientList.add("vijay");
        patientList.add("kumari");
        bean.setPatientList(patientList);
        //return bean;
        return bean ;

    }

}



import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BeanList {
    private ArrayList<String> patientList;

    public ArrayList<String> getPatientList() {
        return patientList;
    }

    public void setPatientList(ArrayList<String> patientList) {
        this.patientList = patientList;
    }

}
```

even this gives

```
 <types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://symp.com/" schemaLocation="http://rajasekhar_pc:9090/NewTestMart/PatientsListService?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>


but i want the wsdl to be in RPC style
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array instead of an ArrayList as JAXB cannot handle collections as top-level objects, only as properties of beans.

Please note that in JAX-WS RPC/encoded is not supported as a messaging mode. You can use JAX-RPC or Apache Axis V1 , if you want to send SOAP encoded messages or create RPC/encoded style WSDL.

Comment: thank you... i have even tried to return a bean which contains list as a property.. but this is also not reflecting rpc style

Comment: no even when i try to return array also it is showing in document style but bot in rpc style

Comment: As I know if you create a bean than you can use collection as property and this works!

Comment: i will update the code with java bean as return type .. please have a look at it... even this is showing in document style

Comment: thank you.. i have updated the code... even JavaBean is not working fine

Comment: You code works fine for me.
Check your XSD and you will see everything ok.

  <xs:complexType name="beanList">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="patientList" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>

Comment: you are getting Soapbinding in rpc style or Doccument style... for me also it's working fine but i want wsdl to be generated in rpc style... which is not happening, because i have to use this wsdl in SalesForce there it wont allow external XSD locations

Comment: then why it is giving schemaLocation="http://rajasekhar_pc:9090/NewTestMart/ProductCatalogService?xsd=1"

Comment: Are you using JAX-WS?

If yes, than note шn JAX-WS RPC/encoded is not supported as a messaging mode. 

You can use JAX-RPC or Apache Axis V1 , f you want to send SOAP encoded messages or create RPC/encoded style WSDL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73125/discussion-between-rajasekhar-and-andrey-e).